# Elasticsearch - seach document with geo_shape based on other document geo_shape

Tags: elasticsearch, geojson, elasticsearch-geo-shape

is there an option to perform search using one query in ElasticSearch like that:

1. Get document with ID = 1
2. This document has a field with geo_shape mapping
3. Get values from that field
4. Search for other documents which geo_shape field intersects with doc(id=1) geo_shape
5. Return found docs

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [pre-indexed shapes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-shape-query.html#_pre_indexed_shape) for this purpose.

```
POST /_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
                "filter": {
                    "geo_shape": {
                        "your_shape_field": {
                            "indexed_shape": {
                                "id": "1",
                                "type": "your_type",
                                "index": "your_index",
                                "path": "shape"
                            },
                            "relation": "intersects"
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

This query will return all documents having `your_shape_field` intersect the `shape` field in document with id 1.

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much!