# Querying geoshape results from different indexes

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation, geospatial

I have the following scenario: I have an index with all possible ads of my platform. These ads contain an object with coordinates (`latitude`/`longitude`).

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "slug": "my-ad-slug",
  "location": {
    "coordinates": {
      "latitude": 1.123456,
      "longitude": 1.987654
    }
  }
```

I also have another index with some locations and their polygons and shapes for geolocation searches.

```
{
  "id": "456",
  "name": "my location",
  "geo_location": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [...]
  }
}
```

My question is: how can I query all ads that are within a certain polygon, since I have two different indexes in this case? Do you see an easy way on doing so?

Thanks y'all!

Comment: Yes, you can do it as explained in this thread provided that `location` is of type `geo_point` (which I don't think it is in your case): https://stackoverflow.com/a/42249514/4604579

Comment: Thanks, @Val, but my case is slightly different. I want to match the on my `ads` index, under `location.coordinates` path to a boundary within `locations`, under `geo_location`. The query is not allowing me to move forward nor compare both data.

Comment: If you have your shapes correctly indexed in index A, then you can use them in queries on index B